# Use of relational operators to reduce use of modulus operator

Tags: c++, modulus

I've been working on an algorithm which requires to calculate (x%M) multiple times. Here x and M are integers. I've come up with following two definitions:

```
int ModUtil(int x,int M)
{
    /* returns (x%M) */
    if(x>=M || x<=-M) x%=M;
    if(x<0) x+=M;
    return x;
}

int ModUtil(int x,int M)
{
    /* returns (x%M) */
    return (x%M + M)%M;
}
```

Method 1 uses 1 modulus operator but alternatively requires 2 relational operators. On the other hand, Method 2 uses 2 modulus operators. Assuming I"ll be calling the above function for about 10^6 times, which of the above two methods is a better choice? In general,modulus operators are more expensive in terms of time than relational operators,  but will it cost any significant effect?

Comment: Does M have some constraints, such as power of 2?

Comment: M is a high value prime number of order 10^9.

Comment: Doesn't `((x%M) + M)%M` = `x&M`? Careful with brackets, I don't remember its precedence.

Comment: 10^6 calls of `%` should finish in a fraction of a second. What's the problem?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I agree with that, but here I want to focus on the better of the two methods rather than just getting the things done.

Comment: Branching can be just as if not more expensive than modulus.

Comment: Compile it with all optimizations, disassemble and count cpu instructions

Comment: @CPPCoder First get things done, if you notice something takes long, improve it if possible. Premature optimization is the base of many, many evils. Always write for clarity first.

Comment: @CPPCoder With numbers this big you need to be careful when using `int`. `INT_MAX` usually is 2^31-1, ca. 2.1e9.

Comment: Once you have correct code you can profile that and you have a baseline for both speed and correctness when you try and optimize it.

Comment: The compiler will do a far better job of optimising this than you can, in a second or two, no errors either.